# How to get a category thumbnail or Image?

Tags: category, magento-1, thumbnail

I am stuck at this point. I want to display a grid of categories thumbnail/image

```
var_dump($_category->getData('thumbnail')); return NULL
```

Even when I do `var_dump($_category->getData());`
here is what's return

```
array(16) { ["entity_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["entity_type_id"]=>string(1) "3"     
["attribute_set_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["parent_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-12-15 18:49:50" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) 
"2014-12-15 19:09:30" ["path"]=> string(5) "1/2/3" ["position"]=> string(1) 
"1" ["level"]=> string(1) "2" ["children_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["path_id"]=> 
string(5) "1/2/3" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["include_in_menu"]=> 
string(1) "1" ["request_path"]=> string(14) "vegetable.html" ["name"]=> 
string(9) "Vegetable" ["url_key"]=> string(9) "vegetable"}
```

this is my code

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName(); // this works?>
                <?php var_dump($_category->getData('thumbnail')) // return null?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getThumbnailImageUrl();
```

But you would have to make some changes to

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php
```

Before editing, copy this file to local and then insert the following code around line 494

```
/**
 * Retrieve Thumbnail image URL
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getThumbnailImageUrl()
{
    $url = false;
    if ($image = $this->getThumbnail()) {
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$image;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Do not extend the core like this please...

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code:

```
$catId = 566;
$imageName = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getImage();
$mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
echo $mediaUrl.'catalog/category/'.$imageName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer

```
->addAttributeToSelect('image');
```

will get the image file name, but i need to use

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get category thumbnail inside `_getHtml() (Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu)`.

First, inside observer `(Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer) _addCategoriesToMenu(...)` function I added `'thumbnail'` to `$categoryData` array.

```
$categoryData = array(
                'name' => $category->getName(),
                'id' => $nodeId,
                'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
                'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
                'thumbnail' => $category->getThumbnail()
            );
```

Second, as mentioned by michael above I added `<thumbnail/>` attribute in `Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml -> frontend/category/collection/attributes`.

Now, each `$child` object in the foreach loop of `_getHtml()` function contains "thumbnail" data attribute with image name (if present).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<thumbnail/>` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml` -> `frontend/category/collection/attributes`.